# Цикл с параметром

Tags: c++

Вывести на печать значения функции z=sin(x)+cos(x),находящиеся в интервале (-0,2; 0,8) для x изменяющегося на отрезке [4,-6] с шагом 0,91.
Объясните задачу

как я её понял:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "iostream.h"
#include "conio.h"
void main()
{
clrscr();
float x,z;
int i;
for (i=-6; (i<=4) && (z>=-0.2) && (z<=0.8); i=i+0.91)
{
x=i;
z=sin(x)+cos(x);
cout <<i<<" "<<z<<" ";
}

getch();
}
```

Только не работает :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
double i
```

Т.к. прибавляем к нему не целое. На принадлежность `z` интервалу нужно проверку делать в теле цикла, и при удачном стечении обстоятельств выводить значение.

В общем случае так:

```
for (double i = -6; i <= 4; i += 0.91)
{
    double z = sin(i) + cos(i);
    if (z > -0.2 && z < 0.8)
        std::cout << "f(" << i << ") = " << z << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно вывести значения функции в интервале `(-0,2; 0,8)`?
Тогда нужен цикл для `(х) [4,-6] с шагом 0,91`. То есть это:

```
for( x=(-6); x<=4; x+0,91)
```

Потом считаешь функцию  `z=sin(x)+cos(x)`, и выводишь только то, что находится в пределах 
`(-0,2; 0,8)`. Подчеркиваю, это если я правильно понял постановку задачи!

Comment: Я тоже задачу не совсем понял)

Comment: у Рома Тюлин тоже верно,даже ошибку сам исправил) можете компилировать спокойно))